# Back camera android not work

Tags: android, camera, back

I have a problem. I want execute example app from 
http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidCamera/article.html
It works.
But when change in code CAMERA_FACING_FRONT to CAMERA_FACING_BACK I see in LogCat: Camera Error -1

I execute it on my Samsung Galaxy SII

```
private int findFrontFacingCamera() {
int cameraId = -1;
// Search for the front facing camera
int numberOfCameras = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfCameras; i++) {
  CameraInfo info = new CameraInfo();
  Camera.getCameraInfo(i, info);
  if (info.facing == CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
    Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "Camera found");
    cameraId = i;
    break;
  }
}
return cameraId;
```

}

Current code

```
private int findFrontFacingCamera() {
    int cameraId = -1;
    // Search for the front facing camera
    int numberOfCameras = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfCameras; i++) {
      CameraInfo info = new CameraInfo();
      Camera.getCameraInfo(i, info);
      if (info.facing == CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK) {
        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "Camera found " + info.facing );
        cameraId = i;
        break;
      }
    }
    return cameraId;
  }
```

logCat:

```
  04-30 21:14:36.400: D/MakePhotoActivity(8793): Camera found 0
04-30 21:14:36.400: I/Camera(8793): sendBroadcast intent.stop.app-in-app
04-30 21:14:36.650: D/libEGL(8793): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_mali.so
04-30 21:14:36.655: D/libEGL(8793): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_mali.so
04-30 21:14:36.660: D/libEGL(8793): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mali.so
04-30 21:14:36.665: D/(8793): Device driver API match
04-30 21:14:36.665: D/(8793): Device driver API version: 10
04-30 21:14:36.665: D/(8793): User space API version: 10 
04-30 21:14:36.665: D/(8793): mali: REVISION=Linux-r2p4-02rel0 BUILD_DATE=Thu Oct 25 08:43:05 KST 2012 
04-30 21:14:36.685: D/OpenGLRenderer(8793): Enabling debug mode 0
04-30 21:16:21.695: D/dalvikvm(8793): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 0ms
04-30 21:16:21.775: D/dalvikvm(8793): GC_EXPLICIT freed 78K, 14% free 9467K/10883K, paused 9ms+4ms, total 82ms
04-30 21:16:22.010: E/Camera(8793): Error -1
```

rest of code

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // do we have a camera?
    if (!getPackageManager()
        .hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) {
      Toast.makeText(this, "No camera on this device", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
          .show();
    } else {
      cameraId = findFrontFacingCamera();
      if (cameraId < 0) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "No front facing camera found.",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      } else {
        camera = Camera.open(cameraId);
      }
    }
  }

  public void onClick(View view) {

    camera.takePicture(null, null,
        new PhotoHandler(getApplicationContext()));
  }
```

permission:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT"/>
     <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
```

Comment: Is "Camera found" printed? could you try log numberOfCameras?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest adding some logs to display the values of `info.facing` and `CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT`. `CAMERA_FACING_BACK` has a value of 0 and `CAMERA_FACING_FRONT = 1`. Check the value in `info.facing`, which is what the device returns

If you're accessing the backfacing camera, you can try 
 `camera = Camera.open();`.

There might be a hardware or device permission reason why you are getting a runtime error.

Comment: Current code:  ' private int findFrontFacingCamera() {
    int cameraId = -1;
    // Search for the front facing camera
    int numberOfCameras = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfCameras; i++) {
      CameraInfo info = new CameraInfo();
      Camera.getCameraInfo(i, info);
      if (info.facing == CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK) {
        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "Camera found " + info.facing );
        cameraId = i;
        break;
      }
    }
    return cameraId;
  }'

Comment: Log: 04-30 21:14:36.400: D/MakePhotoActivity(8793): Camera found 0

Comment: That means the back camera is found. As TanjaV mentioned, CAMERA_FACING_BACK has a value of 0

Comment: You should post your code into your question. its difficult to understand in the comment

Comment: But it looks like its correct, because you're getting Camera found = 0